# Calling functions passed as arguments in Lua

Tags: functional-programming, lua

I have this code

```
Option = { }


function Option.nothing( )
  local self = { isNone = true, isSome = false }

  function self:orElse( alt )
    return alt
  end

  function self:map( f )
    return Option.nothing( )
  end

  function self:exec( f )
  end

  function self:maybe( alt, f )
    return alt
  end

  return self
end



function Option.just( val )
  local self = { isNone = false, isSome = true }
  local value = val

  function self:orElse( alt )
    return value
  end

  function self:map( f )
    return Option.just( f(value) )
  end

  function self:exec( f )
    f( value )
  end

  function self:maybe( alt, f )
    return f(value)
  end

  return self
end



function printOpt( opt )
  local str = opt.maybe( "Nothing", function(s) return "Just " .. s end )
  print( str )
end


x = Option.nothing( )
y = Option.just( 4 )

printOpt(x)
printOpt(y)
```

But I keep getting 'attempt to call local 'f' (a nil value)' here:

```
  function self:maybe( alt, f )
    return f(value)
  end
```

It seems I'm having trouble calling a function passed as a argument.

Answer (score 6):

You declared the function as `self:maybe()`, but you're calling it as `opt.maybe()`. You should call it as `opt:maybe()`.

Declaring it as `self:maybe(alt, f)` is equivalent to declaring it as `self.maybe(self, alt, f)`. So if you call it with a `.` you need 3 args. You're passing 2, so `self` ends up as `"Nothing"`, and `alt` ends up as the function object.

However, by calling it as `opt:maybe("Nothing", f)` this is equivalent to saying `opt.maybe(opt, "Nothing", f)` which provides the required 3 args.

Comment: Mike, if you're going to edit my code, please make sure you're actually correct. The first arg to `maybe()`, i.e. `self`, does indeed get the value `"Nothing"`. It does not get `nil`.

Comment: In case you're confused, the one call to `opt.maybe()` in the OP's source calls it as `opt.maybe("Nothing", function(s)...end)`